# Webstorm gives strange green background in html file

Tags: html, webstorm

[image]

Okay sorry for the little bit big picture (problem is my retina screen I guess). Not sure how to set width in stackoverflow.

But my question is, if I make a html file in webstorm some of the back ground is green, and I don't understand why and I find it kind of ugly, so I would wish to make this back ground just normal. Is there some option where I can do this ?

Comment: yes, you can edit any colour in preferences -> editor/appearance

Comment: @atmd I've searched for an hour, but I can't find it, I can litteraly change any color except this one

Answer (score 7):

[image]

I needed to uncheck this. I'm not sure why or how this got in, doesn't seem to be standard.

Comment: You have created a custom injection rule somehow (most likely accidentally when you have not looked at screen and typing fast). As you can see that entry does not have "Built-in" in "Scope" column which means it was created by user. If you do not need it (which is the case) -- just delete it.

Comment: I had this turn on recently from the Docker plugin